# Conditions for compactness of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, integral-operators

Let $A$ be an bounded operator on a Hilbert space with ONB $\{e_n\}_n$. I am looking for precise conditions on $\langle e_n, A e_m \rangle$ to guarantee that $A$ is compact (i.e. the limit of finite rank operators). It is known that $A$ is trace-class if $$ \sum_{m} \sum_n|\langle e_n, A e_m \rangle| < \infty $$ and the trace class operators are within the compacts. However, what if $A$ is not trace class? If $A$ were diagonal we know the sufficient and necessary condition is that $$\langle e_n, A e_n \rangle\to 0 \qquad( n\to\infty)\,.$$

However, what if $A$ is not diagonal? Is there a criterion in terms of the decay of $\langle e_n, A e_m \rangle$?

Comment: For the identity operator $ \langle e_n, Ae_m \rangle \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ or $m \to \infty$. There is no simple characterization in terms of these inner products (and that is why you don't find any such theorem in books)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, thanks for your comment and pointing this out. I edited to make it more sensible incase someone comes up with a clever argument.

Comment: To illustrate how hard this problem can be assume that there exists a sequence of scalars $\{c_n\}_{n\geq0}$ such that $⟨e_n, Ae_m⟩ = c_{n+m}$.  In this case $A$ is called a *Hankel* operator.  Then Hartman's (resp Nehari's) Theorem says that $A$ is *compact* (resp. *bounded*) iff there exists a continuous (resp. bounded measurable) function on the circle whose positive Fourier coefficients are given by the $c_n$.

Answer (score 3):

For $m\geq n$, let $A^{m, n}$ be the $m\times m$ matrix given by

$$
A^{m, n}_{i, j} =
  \left\{\matrix{
    0, & \text{if } i, j\leq n, \cr
    \langle e_i, Ae_j\rangle , & \text{otherwise}.
    }
  \right.
$$
For example,
$$
A^{3,2} =
\pmatrix{
0 & 0 &\langle e_1, Ae_3\rangle  \cr
0 & 0 &\langle e_2, Ae_3\rangle  \cr
\langle e_3, Ae_1\rangle  & \langle e_3, Ae_2\rangle  & \langle e_3, Ae_3\rangle 
}.
$$

**Theorem**.  The operator  $A$ is compact if and only if $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} \|A^{m, n}\| =0$.

*Proof*.  Let $P_n$ be the orthogonal projection onto the span of the first $n$ basis vectors and notice that, for
$m\geq n$,  the
matrix of
$$
  P_mAP_m -   P_nAP_n
  $$
coincides with $A^{m,n}$ inside the top left $m\times m$ block of entries, and has
zero entries everywhere else.  It follows that
$$
  \|A^{m, n}\| = \|  P_mAP_m -   P_nAP_n\|,
  $$
so the condition regarding the limit in the statement is equivalent to $\{P_nAP_n\}_n$ being  a Cauchy
sequence.

As we are working within the space of bounded operators on a Hilbert space, which is complete, we may replace
"Cauchy" by "converging" in the sentence above.

Assuming that this condition is true, that is, that $P_nAP_n$ converges,  then the limit operator  has the same matrix as
$A$  (I'm assuming we are using  Physicist's inner-product, which is   conjugate linear in the first variable), and hence
coincides with $A$.   In other words
$$
  \lim_nP_nAP_n = A.
  $$
Since $P_nAP_n$ is finite rank, hence compact, and since the space of compact operators is closed, it
follows that $A$ is compact. This proves the "if" part.  As for the "only if" part, suppose that $A$ is compact.   Using
that $\{P_n\}_n$ is uniformly bounded and converges to the identity operator in the strong (pointwise) topology one shows
that
$P_nAP_n$ converges to $A$ in norm, so $\{P_nAP_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence  which we have already agreed to be
equivalent to the condition in the statement.

---

Remarks:

1. Since $A^{m, n}$ is a finite matrix, its norm is (in principle) computable in terms of the $\langle e_i, Ae_j\rangle $, as
   required.
2. Computing norms of finite matrices is a hard numerical problem, so this criterion might not be as useful as the OP would like.

Comment: Thanks Ruy, actually interesting claim, I would be interested in a proof. Since we know norms on finite vector spaces are equivalent, this could be translated to a claim on the largest of the matrix elements multiplied by $m$, no? I mean something like if $$ \lim_{m,n\to\infty} m \max_{i,j\in{1,\dots,m}}|\langle e_i, A e_j\rangle| = 0\,? $$

Comment: OK, I have added a proof.  Regarding the equivalence of norms, it is true that all norms are equivalent on a finite dimensional space but the way in which these equivalences behave (the constants involved) vary in an uncontrollable way and I doubt that a cleaner condition may be obtained, such as the one you propose in your comment.