# Example of a "weak" Compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, integral-operators

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space with ONB $\{e_n\}_n$. Following [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814861/conditions-for-compactness-of-operator/), I would like to find an example of a bounded operator $A$ such that

- $A$ is compact.
- $A$ is not $p$-Schatten for *any* $p\geq 1$.
- $A$ is not finite rank, diagonal, Toeplitz or Hankel.

Answer (score 0):

Take any sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ in $c_0$ which is not in $l^p$ for any $p$, and consider the corresponding  **diagonal** operator with diagonal entries $x_n$.  This operator has all of the required properties, except that it is diagonal.

To make it non-diagonal, conjugate it by a random unitary matrix and, unless you are very very unlucky, it will not be diagonal, Toeplitz or Hankel, and hence will satisfy **all** of the conditions.